# I can't determine why it's raising this SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

https://pastebin.com/TZdMx3pM
Here's the code

This error is raised on line 291:

```
  File "marketTrader.py", line 291
    stock_list.remove(preferredStock[0])
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am runing on MacOS. Does it matter if I'm using Python 2 or 3?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Often a syntax error *points to* an unrelated line when a closing parenthesis is missing on a previous line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @wwii I didn't? Also thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close a parentheses on the previous line, 290.

This kind of syntax error does not depend on Python version or OS.

You could have spotted it easily using an IDE (e.g. PyCharm, EMACS) or a static analyser (e.g. pycheck).

Answer (score 0):

It's a missing `')'`

Check the line before:

```
print(': Starting Active Trader with preferred stock {}...'.format([preferredStock[0]])
stock_list.remove(preferredStock[0])
```

There is missing a close bracket for print.